# How the button method gets the value passed by [postmessage]

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I have been thinking for too long, but there is no substantial progress on this issue, so please ask everyone, what are the good suggestions and solutions.

**This is my LWC.JS file**

```
import { LightningElement, track} from 'lwc';
import getAccount from '@salesforce/apex/cpcs_CustomerServicesController.getAccount';
import HideHeader from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/HideHeader';
import { loadStyle} from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

export default class CustomerService_LWC extends LightningElement {

    @track record = [];
    @track labelRecord = [];
    @track accInfo = [];

    connectedCallback() {
        // initialize component
        loadStyle(this, HideHeader)
        window.addEventListener("message", (event) =>{

            if(event.origin === 'https://qasp.yhcrm.cn'){
                var dataVal1 = event.origin;
                var dataVal2 = event.data;
                console.log('get event successfully1！' + dataVal1);
                console.log('get event successfully2！' + JSON.stringify(dataVal2));
                // Handle the message
            }else{
                console.log('***11231');
                return;
            }

        }, false);
    }

    page1Btn(){
        getAccount({accId: '1234'})
            .then(result => {
                this.accInfo = result;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
            });
    }
}
```

**This is my Apex file**

```
public with sharing class cpcs_CustomerServicesController {
    // get label
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Account> getAccount(String accId) {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'accId = ' + accId);
        return [SELECT ID,Name,U_Gender__c,U_Mobile__c,U_City__c,U_SubscribeSceneDCode__c,U_Description__c,
                        U_QrSceneStr__c,Type,U_BusinessDCode__c,U_QrScene__c,
                        U_Source__c,U_BusinessName__c,U_SyncStatus__c,U_SyncInfo__c,
                        U_RegDate__c,U_FollowUpTime__c
                        FROM Account LIMIT 1];
    }
}
```

**This is my LWC.HTML file**

[image]

Question: How to pass dataVal2 to getAccount(**accId :dataVal2** ) in the [page1Btn]JS method and call the [page1Btn] method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to pass the `dataVal2` by using `this.` which makes it class variable and will be persistent

Pls check the code below: (`@track dataVal2;` is not really needed dataVal2 is not referenced in HTML)

```
export default class CustomerService_LWC extends LightningElement {

    @track record = [];
    @track labelRecord = [];
    @track accInfo = [];
    @track dataVal2;
    connectedCallback() {
        // initialize component
        loadStyle(this, HideHeader)
        window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {

            if (event.origin === 'https://qasp.yhcrm.cn') {
                this.dataVal1 = event.origin;
                this.dataVal2 = event.data;
                console.log('get event successfully1！' + this.dataVal1);
                console.log('get event successfully2！' + JSON.stringify(this.dataVal2));
                // Handle the message
            } else {
                console.log('***11231');
                return;
            }

        }, false);
    }

    page1Btn() {
        getAccount({ accId: this.dataVal2 })
            .then(result => {
                this.accInfo = result;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
            });
    }
}
```